# Docs Document is closed, its contents cannot be updated

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I tried this code:

```
var doc1 = DocumentApp.openById("ididididddddddddddidididididididi")
doc1.getBody().editAsText().appendText('hello text here')
doc1.saveAndClose()


doc1.getBody().editAsText().appendText('second text here')
doc1.saveAndClose()
```

but it return error:

> Exception: Document is closed, its contents cannot be updated.

Reason why use `saveAndClose()` func, the text that i append on doc too long so it return error:

> ScriptError: Too many changes applied before saving document.
> Please save changes in smaller batches using Document.saveAndClose(),
> then reopen the document with Document.openById().

There doesn't seem to be a way to fix this............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you reopen the document?

> Please save changes in smaller batches using Document.saveAndClose(),
> then reopen the document with Document.openById().

```
var doc1 = DocumentApp.openById("ididididddddddddddidididididididi")
doc1.getBody().editAsText().appendText('hello text here')
doc1.saveAndClose()

var doc1 = DocumentApp.openById("ididididddddddddddidididididididi")
doc1.getBody().editAsText().appendText('second text here')
doc1.saveAndClose()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).